# How to Judge the same thread in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

```
The threads has the same thread ident but diffent pid, Is it the same thread? Why they has the same  thread ident? how can i Judge the same thread?
```

```
def send_pic(txt):
    print(f'send_pic {txt}  pid:{os.getpid() } tid:{threading.current_thread().ident}')
    time.sleep(4)
    print('send_pic  %s ..ok  ' % txt)
    return 'ok'


def send_video(txt):
    print(f'send_video {txt}  pid:{os.getpid() } tid:{threading.current_thread().ident}')
    time.sleep(3)
    print('send_video  %s ..ok  ' % txt)
    return 'ok'
```

send_pic @8@  pid:23548 tid:140735887565696

send_video #9#  pid:23542 tid:140735887565696

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it the same thread?

Those messages appear to have been printed by two different processes. Any given thread can only exist in *one* process. So, No, It is not possible for the same thread to have printed both of those two messages.

---

FYI: The [`threading.Thread.native_id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=ident#threading.Thread.native_id) attribute is supposed to be unique among all of the threads currently running on the whole system. I don't know what problem you are trying to solve, but maybe changing `ident` to `native_id` in your code would help.

The `native_id` attribute supposedly is not available in every Python implementation, but it *is* supposed to be available in Windows, MacOS, Linux, and some other Unix-like operating systems.